# How to do nested routing for multiple components in single page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying three components in one single App.js. I need to route these components :
I have main container CSV.js in which two components TABLE.js and FILEUPLOAD.js is present. The main route would be /csv-app. When a row in table is clicked the route should be /csv-app/table/:id

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/2nd-example-nested-routing) the problem is quite easy solvable. See the nested routing example.

Answer (score 0):

you should get something like this using React Router Dom

```
import { Switch, Route, Link, Redirect, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

const Table = props =>(
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/csv-app/table/:id">
            "table row ....."
        </Route>

        <Route axact path="/csv-app/table">
            <table>
                <Link to={`/csv-app/table/${2}`}></Link>
            </table>
        </Route>
    </Switch>
)

const FileUpload = props => (<> file upload component </>)

const Csv = props => (
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/csv-app/table'>
        <Table />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path='/csv-app/fileupload'>
        <FileUpload />
    </Route>

    <Redirect to='/csv-app' />
</Switch>
)


const App = props => (
<Router basename="/">
    <Csv />
</Router>
)
```